# Where I should accept Firefox Add-on Distribution Agreement?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

When I try to sign an addon I've received a message without validation_url. But in details I see information about Firefox Add-on Distribution Agreement and Review Policies and Rules. Where I should accept them?

I haven't found information about this message: https://addons-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/api/signing.html

```
Upload: xpi = c:\temp\xpi_8e03dc5f6de9\xpi.zip, id = example@example.com, version = 1.0.1.1, user = user:42085444:111, key = 1bb945266bf370170a656350d9b640cbcaf70e671cf753c410e604219cdd9267
```

...

```
Upload Response: {"detail":"Before starting, please read and accept our Firefox Add-on Distribution Agreement as well as our Review Policies and Rules. The Firefox Add-on Distribution Agreement also links to our Privacy Notice which explains how we handle your information."}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Should accept Firefox Add-on Distribution Agreement and Review Policies and Rules here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/addon/api/key/

Comment: The world is a better place because of you!